# Does updating a Couchbase document replace the original document?

Tags: couchbase

I started to use Couchbase recently. As stated [here](https://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Generational+Append-Only+Storage+Files) Couchbase is an append-only DB. As far as i understand this means that my updated document is attached to Couchbase's B+-tree. Or does it actually replace the original document?

If the updated document is appended what happens to the original document? Does is just persist or will it become deleted at some point through auto compaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase can configured to handle the update as an atomic transaction or not. In Couchbase land, one must consider the two methods Couchbase stores documents: memory and disk.

I suspect your question is directed within the context of how Couchbase stores the documents on disk after an update.

After a document has been mutated, Couchbase makes the newly mutated document available in memory first for other readers to see and then eventually persists it to disk. The latter can be configured to be atomic too, by the way.

Each document mutation generates a new CAS value to be associated with the updated document. Think of the two CAS values as unique identifiers for the two versions of your document: prior and current. Both are stored as two separate documents in memory and on disk.

So rather than rewriting the disk block storing the earlier version of the document, Couchbase will store the new document on disk as a completely separate document. Incidentally, Couchbase chooses a location on disk by determining where the last of any other documents were written and writing the new document to disk immediately after it.

Garbage collection, or compaction as Couchbase refers to it, will eventually stop by and look for old documents that have expired and eject them keeping only the most recent versions. Additionally, the compaction process will fill in the gaps on disk attempting to keep a contiguous storage footprint.

These are all configurable to be optionally more atomic-like, but the architecture really shines when you have a use case whereby eventually consistent is acceptable.

Here's a reference on how to handle concurrent document mutations at the application tier, but does a pretty good job explaining how the CAS value works: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/concurrent-mutations-cluster.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I already knew about CAS but I was not sure about the append process. Thanks for your explanation.